# Logging in with MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Identity to handle my user, and usually in the Register function both the `Username` and `Email` is set equal to the Email in the `RegisterViewModel`

In my view I added an extra input, called username, and I added it to the model.

So in the code below you can see me change the value of `Username` from the email value in the model, to my new username value in the model

```
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

And it works great, it's saved as it should be in the database etc.

BUT

After I log off, and try to log in again, I am not able to log in.

And the thing is, if I change back so that `username` is equal to the email like it normally is, then it works.

But shouldn't I be able to log in, because the email field in the identity database is still the email the user entered, so why does changing the username affect this?

And how can it be fixed? Thank you.

**LOGIN CODE**

```
// POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the user login code.

Comment: You mentioned adding an additional `username` property to the view, but you are trying to login with `model.Email` - is this correct?  Do you not want `model.username` instead?  Might need your login view to make sure your are mapping to the right model fields.